# How to create media image entities like an image field?

Tags: 8, entities, media, workflows

I have been using a content type **Article** with an **Image** field to allow users to upload images.  I have decided that I want to use media image entities instead because the images will be re-used on multiple nodes, so it would be better to use a module like [Entity Browser](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_browser) to allow admins to pick the images they want to use.

Following [this tutorial](https://www.webwash.net/manage-media-assets-drupal-8/), I set up Media Entity, Media Entity Image, Embed, and Embed Entity on my site.  I can now add entities from the `/media/add/image` page.

But, with using this set of modules, the workflow has changed.

**Image field on content type workflow**

1. User uploads images in the field when creating a node.

**Media entity image + content type/embed workflow**

1. User uploads images.
2. User creates a node.
3. User embeds the images on the node.

So actually this new workflow has more steps than the old one.  Is there a way to "embed" creation of media entities as if it was just an **image** field attached to the content type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like exactly the use case [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form) was built for:

> Provides a widget for inline management (creation, modification, removal) of referenced entities.